# Azure to Azure Site recovery doesn't delete NIC on re-protect

Tags: azure-site-recovery

We are using Azure to Azure Site Recovery for our Virtual Machines, but when we fail them over and re-protect, the Virtual Machines are cleaned up (removed), but the NIC still remains (and still has the Static IP associated with it).  How do we clean up the VM?

As a bit of background we use a script to associate Public IP to the NIC when failing over based on this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-Public-IP-and-NSG-to-a6bb8fee

Is it possible the fact we change the NIC (associate NSG and Public IP) means that azure doesn't delete it?

How can we delete it automatically?  I can't see a way to run a post-script on re-protect.

Comment: When you say "Virtual Machines are cleaned up" have deleted the failed-over VMs?

Comment: Yup the failed-over VMS are deleted.